# Disabling SSH password login for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ssh, security, root, remote

A have a remote server for which I want to disable remote login using a password for root and other users.  I have gone through a few articles on the Internet about how to do that and I have the following list of things to do/change:

1. create private key authentication using SSH keys for all users ( I have already done this )
2. Set the following settings in `sshd_config` :

   - set `PermitRootLogin without-password`
   - set `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`
   - set `PasswordAuthentication no`
   - set `UsePAM no`
   - set `AllowUsers root otheruser`
3. restart `ssh` using `sudo service ssh reload`

However, I am not sure exactly which changes are to be made to the `sshd_config` file and I don't want to be locked out of my remote server.

1. If I want to be able to login as root and other users using only SSH keys, what changes do I make?
2. If I want to prevent remote root login at all what changes do I make (and how much more secure it is as compared to remote root login using SSH keys)?
3. If I prevent remote root login at all by making changes to sshd_config file, how will I ever be able to login as ROOT if I want to in future?

Please answer these questions as explicitly as possible and pardon me for lack of trying things as I am completely horrified of the possibility of getting locked out of my own remote server.

Comment: Some of the points at the TODO list are included here: [Disable password access through SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1991/disable-password-access-through-ssh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> set "UsePAM no" in sshd_config file

You don't want to turn of PAM.

> 1. If I want to be able to login as root and otheruser using only SSH keys, what changes do I make?

To achieve this, these options are related:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowUsers root otheruser
PubkeyAuthentication yes     # missing in your list, but should be on by default)
```

> 2. If I want to prevent remote root login at all what changes do I make (and how much more secure it is as compared to remote root login using SSH keys)?

Set `PermitRootLogin no` and `AllowUsers otheruser`.

> 3. If I prevent remote root login at all by making changes to sshd_config file, how will I ever be able to login as ROOT if I want to in future?

You will log in with your non-root user and use `sudo` to edit the configuration files and restart `sshd`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the last point to use "sudo" for editing sshd_config, it asks for sudo password for "otheruser" when trying to do that. So won't it be an issue if we disable password for otheruser and try to do this.

Comment: It depends on how sudo is configured. You are disabling only password authentication in SSH so it wont be any issue.

Comment: ok. I am also using dreamweaver and its interact with the remote server via sftp using "otheruser" password. I have implemented the 1st part of ur answer( i.e. disabling remote login with password) and I can still tranfer files to the server using dreamweaver connection. Is it expected behavior? (because if it is, isnt it a security hole when someone tries to sftp with root)

Comment: If you had the connection opened before restarting sshd service, then it is possible.

Comment: yes it was because connection was opened before reasating ssh. Confirmed it. Is there any way to allow password login for "otheruser" and only SSH key authentication for root? ( Dreamweaver doesn't allow SSH keys! )

Comment: Just remove the `PasswordAuthentication no` (or change it to `yes`).

Comment: I have done all the above, but still able to log in with username and password as well as key

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1440509/1713168

> Inside the directory /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ there is only one .conf
> file (50-cloud-init.conf), but inside it contains the line:
> PasswordAuthentication yes
>
> I changed the line to #PasswordAuthentication no
>
> and i restarted the ssh. Now is working. I can only access with the
> ssh key.