# Ubuntu 23 remove login password (again)

Tags: ssh, login, password

Asking again as current config according to many [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894237/disabling-ssh-password-login-for-ubuntu) shown are still allowing me to log in with password.
I have successfully set up ssl cert login.

Here is my sshd_config (without commented out parts for brevity)

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Checking a different server config where the same settings are in place I get a response of

```
No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)
```

which is exactly what I want, no possible way to enter password.

The only difference is that it works on Ubuntu 18.04 but fails on Ubuntu 23.04

The working config is:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: did you restart sshd after the change?

Comment: yes I restarted it and reboot server

Answer (score 0):

It shows that "UsePAM yes"
Maybe compare PAM settings between the hosts.

AuthenticationMethods  "publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive" inside the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

Or there is something extra in the /etc/pam.d/sshd.

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines IMHO, but perhaps the solution is to keep PAM (for account and session checks) but disable `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`? See for example [Debian 12 - Unable to login using my key, and still able to login using password, but this is disabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749406/65304)

Comment: Possible, I have never used this setting in PAM.

Comment: Ubuntu versions different, but I think these setup should same on the OS.

What is the setup on the older OS?

Comment: added KbdInteractiveAuthentication no but no change

Comment: If you remove password from AuthenticationMethods from the file:  /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: or maybe set PasswordAuthentication no

Answer (score 0):

It seems the line

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

containing

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

was the issue, the reason I did not look here initially was that I expected any statement following in the main conf would override whatever was set prior in the included files.

This is not the case.
I commented out the include line and all is working as expected